# gotoxy function in turbo c

Tags: c, turbo-c++

How can I set x and y in Based on pixel in gotoxy(x,y) function?

Comment: Putting more question marks doesn't make a sentence more question-ish.

Comment: @Matinho: Maybe each question mark cancels out a previous one and we are now left with no question at all :-)

Comment: See [here](http://electrosofts.com/cgraphics/). Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

`gotoxy` is not part of Pascal - it's an extension found in some implementations of Pascal and is probably implemented in a library. For C you can get similar results using a library such as `ncurses`.

Comment: correct and I guess the OP is asking about Borland's Turbo C, which, I think, has such a function. It's not clear what the actual problem is. (the original title mentions turbo c)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The console is only a two-dimensional buffer of character cells and you can set the cursor to one of those cells. They have no relationship to the pixels that may be used to draw the characters.

Answer (score 1):

gotoxy() is character oriented (and only works in MS-DOS character mode).  You cannot draw a character at a specific *pixel* position using gotoxy() and you cannot do it in character mode in any case.

Support for 16 bit MS-DOS applications using graphics modes is limited and troublesome on modern Windows systems.  You would do better to discard your 30 year old compiler and use something that will directly target the actual OS you are running on!  You can then create an application that uses a graphics window and GDI calls (or any number of higher level APIs) to draw text at any position, any size, and any font.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly like this.

```
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    gotoxy(x, y)

    return 0; 
}
```